# Windows API animated window controls

Tags: windows, api, animation, dialog

Lets say I have a window with 2 dialogs, each having its own set of controls/information.
One is displayed on the window and the other is hidden, and I have a button switching between them.
How would I animate the transition between the 2 dialogs, like having it slide back and forth?

Note: I'm trying to use only the windows api for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans is correct, you can use the Windows API AnimateWindow.

[AnimateWindow Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

here an example:

```
int CALLBACK EventDialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{ 
  switch (uMsg) 
  { 
    case WM_INITDIALOG: 
    { 
      AnimateWindow(hwndDlg, 100, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE); 
      return 1; 
    } 
    case WM_PAINT: 
    { 
      return 1; 
    } 
  } 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning 1 for WM_PAINT?